# Is it possible to use encoding for bitmap fonts in dvips?

Tags: dvips, font-map

In the process of creation of `.ps` file, `dvips` reads "`.`*nnn*`pk`" fonts. Those fonts cannot carry encoding information (in contrast to Type3 or Type1 fonts). But in `.map` files encoding information *can* be given.

Is it possible to use `.map` file to associate `.enc` file with a given PK font?

`.map` files allow "ReEncodeFont" parameter, something like the following:

```
lhr10 "Myenc ReEncodeFont" <my.enc
```

Is it possible to use it? Or maybe some other method, like hacking `.ps` file directly? (converting PK fonts to Type1 or Type3 is not to be considered)

**UPDATE**

The following quote from p.12 of pdftex manual looks promising:

> Starting with version 1.40.19, an encoding file can also be specified for bitmap pk fonts. In this case, it as-
>   signs the glyph names from the given encoding vector, which can be used with the \pdfglyphtounicode
>   primitive (q.v.). For example: ...

Is it possible to use similar trick for `dvips`?

---

Here is the full example how to use encoding for PK fonts in pdftex:

Copy `tex256.enc` from distro to current directory and change entry `/idieresis % 239` to `/uni044F`, then process the following file with `pdftex`:

```
\pdfcompresslevel=0 \pdfobjcompresslevel=0
\pdfmapline{lhr10 <tex256.enc}
\font\tenrm=lhr10 \tenrm
^^ef
\end
```

After this you get copyable bitmap character.

Is it possible to reverse-engineer the created pdf and add similar stuff directly to `.ps` produced by `dvips`?

---

It seems the following code in PDF is responsible for associating the encoding with PK file:

```
/Type /Encoding
/Differences [239/uni044F]
```

What is the equivalent of this code in PostScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're in luck! The original author of `dvips`, Tomas Rokicki, has “come out of retirement” (so to speak—I just mean he wasn't working on `dvips` for a while) to change this, and is giving a talk about it at TUG 2019.

You can see his preprint [here](http://tug.org/tug2019/preprints/rokicki-pdfbitmap.pdf), and the GitHub repo with the source code [here](https://github.com/rokicki/type3search).

> You can test my proposed changes to the `dvips` output files without updating your distribution or building a new version of `dvips`. The Perl script `addencodings.pl` reads a PostScript file generated by `dvips` on standard input and writes the PostScript file that would be generated by a modified `dvips` on standard output. No additional files are required for this testing; the default encodings for the standard TEX Live fonts are built in to the Perl script.

The latest version of `addencodings.pl` is [here](https://github.com/rokicki/type3search/blob/master/addencodings.pl) (permanent link to latest as of today: [here](https://github.com/rokicki/type3search/blob/a70b5f3/addencodings.pl)).

Comment: I don't believe it!