# Why does changing the encoding not work in pdfTeX for Type1 fonts?

Tags: pdftex, font-encodings

Using `pdftex` on the following file changes encoding for bitmap font (this can be checked by copy-pasting the text from resulting PDF):

```
\pdfmapline{=cmr10 <cmr10.enc}
`hello world'
\end
```

where `cmr10.enc` is as follows (it differs from default only with `/quoteright` changed to `/uni0027` and `/quoteleft` changed to `/uni0060`):

```
/MyCMRencoding [/Gamma/Delta/Theta/Lambda/Xi/Pi/Sigma/Upsilon/Phi/Psi/Omega/ff/fi/fl/ffi
/ffl/dotlessi/dotlessj/grave/acute/caron/breve/macron/ring/cedilla
/germandbls/ae/oe/oslash/AE/OE/Oslash/suppress/exclam/quotedblright
/numbersign/dollar/percent/ampersand/uni0027/parenleft/parenright
/asterisk/plus/comma/hyphen/period/slash/zero/one/two/three/four/five/six
/seven/eight/nine/colon/semicolon/exclamdown/equal/questiondown/question/at
/A/B/C/D/E/F/G/H/I/J/K/L/M/N/O/P/Q/R/S/T/U/V/W/X/Y/Z/bracketleft
/quotedblleft/bracketright/circumflex/dotaccent/uni0060/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/i
/j/k/l/m/n/o/p/q/r/s/t/u/v/w/x/y/z/endash/emdash/hungarumlaut/tilde/dieresis
/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef
/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef
/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef
/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef
/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef
/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef
/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef
/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef
/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef
/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef
/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef
/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef
/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef
/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef
/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef
/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef/.notdef
] def
```

Now change the `\pdfmapline` to `=cmr10 <cmr10.enc <cmr10.pfb`. `pdftex` fails with this error:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2019/dev/Debian) (preloaded format=pdftex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map} [1] ){cmr10.enc}
</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb

pdfTeX warning: pdftex (file /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/a
msfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb): glyph `uni0027' undefined


pdfTeX warning: pdftex (file /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/a
msfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb): glyph `uni0060' undefined
>
Output written on test.pdf (1 page, 11512 bytes).
Transcript written on test.log.
```

This is strange, because the same enc-file is used in both cases. And bitmap font demonstrates that there is no problem with the name `uni0027`. So, why it is not possible to change encoding for Type1 font in pdftex?

Answer (score 4):

When you use the encoding for a bit map you don't really reencode the font. To see the difference let's exchange A and B in your map:

```
  /B/A
```

If you then compile (I have renamed your map):

```
\pdfmapline{=cmr10 <testcmrenc.enc <cmr10.pfb}
`AB'
\end
```

the output looks like this:

[image]

So the glyphs have been reencoded and have switched place.

If you compile

```
\pdfmapline{=cmr10 <testcmrenc.enc}
`AB'
\end
```

the output looks like this:

[image]

So no reencoding. But if you then do a copy&paste in the pdf the result is

```
`BA'
```

If you remove the mapline command and do a copy and paste:

```
‘AB’
```

Remark that both the order and the quote have changed.

So using an encoding vector with bitmaps doesn't change the encoding of the bitmaps but is "only" used to improve the copy & paste (which is already a quite good thing).

Comment: This is something new to me. What do you mean by "don't really reencode the font"? To me, reencoding is replacing glyph->codepoint mapping which is in Type1 font by default with new glyph->codepoint mapping, where order of glyphs is fixed and glyph names (like `/quoteright` or `/uniXXXX`) specify codepoint for copy-search. Do I get it wrong? What else this glyph->codepoint mapping in Type1 can be used for?

Comment: Maybe I use the wrong terminology: I guess "reencode" is used for a different operation. I just want to change default glyph->codepoint mapping in Type1 font to new glyph->codepoint mapping. Can this operation be done? (and how to call it properly then?)

Comment: what is the problem with my examples? With type1 fonts you can really reencode a font - exchange glyphs in the output (and if you use wrong glyph names some can even be missing, like your quotes) - with bitmaps you can't, there the encoding only helps to improve the copy&paste.

Comment: OK, I see. What I want to do can be achieved using ToUnicode resource (but I don't know how to use it with dvips) or converting the font to `pfa`, editing the glyph name to `/uni0027` and then converting it back to `pfb` (this is OK for me, as I'm going to distribute only PDF documents with embedded fonts - no TeX source).

Comment: You want to change the glyph name in the pdf? Why don't you use cmap or \pdfglyphtounicode?

Comment: well the glyph names in the encoding vector must exist in the pfa: that's the point of the vector, to select glyphs. But regarding dvips: didn't you just link to the answer about the new dvips version? Why don't you try the perl script? https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/503136/2388

Comment: `\pdfglyphtounicode...\pdfgentounicode=1` (aka ToUnicode resource) works perfectly, but I don't know how to use it with tex+dvips+ps2pdf - do you?

Comment: I figured out how to change encoding in the font: `t1disasm cmr10.pfb cmr10.asm`, change quoteright to uni0027 in two places in cmr10.asm, then run `t1asm cmr10.asm cmr10.pfb`

Comment: As for `addencodings.pl` script, this works only with PK fonts. I need to change codepoints for Type1 font. Is it possible to use ToUnicode resource with `tex+dvips+ps2pdf`?

Comment: you really should not change the original pfb, create some with new names.

Comment: I agree. But this works well as a quick drop-in without changing anything. Ideal solution would be to use `\pdfglyphtounicode...\pdfgentounicode=1` (aka ToUnicode resource), but I don't know how to do it with `dvips`... Maybe this is worth asking as  a separate question?